# Swift self.classForCoder in class method

Tags: swift

I am using `self.classForCoder` to log class name using print statement.

I want to log class name in class methods as well without hard-coding.
Is there any dynamic way like `self.classForCoder` to log class name in class method as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `"\(self)"` to log the class name without hard coding it:

```
class Test {
    class func printClassName() {
        print("\(self)")
    }
}

Test.printClassName()
```

> ```
> Test
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Use `type(of: )` function

```
let type = type(of: yourClaseInstance)
print("\(type)")
```

Comment: It is returning `classNAme.Type`. I want to log only class name.